# ProcessBuilder.directory() method usage

Tags: java, directory, processbuilder

What is the utility of the `ProcessBuilder.directory()` method and how is it used? Does it store the directory name?

Comment: I hate to have to say it, but **[RTFD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory()).**

Answer (score 0):

As the javadoc states, the directory() method returns the current directory of the process, the working directory, if you pass it a File, it will set the working directory to that file